# Sendkeys only working when window is activated first

Tags: vb.net, google-chrome, sendkeys

When I have one window open the code works flawless. But when I have more instances running, I need to activate the window first. Seems like `SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle)` is not working correctly?

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

For Each p As System.Diagnostics.Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
    If p.ProcessName = "chrome" AndAlso p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("game") AndAlso p.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle)
        SendKeys.SendWait("{F2}")
    End If
Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
For Each p As System.Diagnostics.Process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
    If p.ProcessName = "chrome" AndAlso p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("chat") AndAlso p.MainWindowHandle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle)
        SendKeys.SendWait("{F2}")
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your complaint? That a window has to be activated/focused before it can receive key events? (Yes.. it would be pretty annoying if every window on your system listened to key events all the time, it'd totally kill multitasking)

Comment: First things first: Have you verified that it actually passes your `If`-statement, i.e. that the `SetForegroundWindow` part of the code is reached? -- Secondly: Show us your `SetForegroundWindow()` declaration so that we can see if it's correct or not.